# Unable to get the output in string replacing?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
      var msg_rec_or_sent=" {"Username":"me:how r u"}  ";
      var new_msg=msg_rec_or_sent.replace(/["  {"Username":"  ']/g, " ") ;
```

The above data I am getting is from some text field and when I replace unwanted characters i get output as

> ```
>             how   u }
> ```

I want output as

> me:how r u?

But i am unable to replace unwanted characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data you get is in JSON format. If so you can do like this:

```
var msg_rec_or_sent = "{\"Username\":\"me:how r u\"}";
var msg_rec_or_sent_json = JSON.parse(msg_rec_or_sent);
var new_msg = msg_rec_or_sent_json.Username;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace string literally, you can do like this.

```
s     = "hoge:fuga";
new_s = s.replace("hoge", "");
```

If there is no multiple `hoge` in `s`, problem won't occur. :)